# Is there a way to scale up RabbitMQ RPC?

Tags: performance, rabbitmq, rpc

Hi I'm using RabbitMQ RPC to distribute tasks to workers (Request/Response)
I studied rpc_client.py and rpc_server.py on the RabbitMQ tutorial and I saw to scale up we must run another process (rpc_server).
I want to assign about 1k tasks per second but it's too slow
Can you help me to solve this problem
System Spec
RAM : 8GB
CPU : Intel® Core™ i7-7700 CPU @ 3.60GHz × 8

Answer (score 0):

In order to scale you can either run multiple processes of python server or use  [multithreading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) to handle the requests. Ofcourse it would be important to use a threadsafe client library for  RabbitMQ like [AMQPStorm](https://www.amqpstorm.io/).
[Here](https://github.com/xiaowenjie21/rpc_example1/blob/master/rpc_server.py) is another example of multithreading using [Pika](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library (note that Pika is not threadsafe)